# Parallel run using testng

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to execute parallel run using testng.
i am trying to run test 4 time parallel. But it runs only one time.

testng.xml

```
<suite name="My suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="4">
  <test name="Default test" group-by-instances="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="org.com.DemoClass"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Default test -->  
</suite> <!-- Default suite -->
```

Demo class.

```
public class DemoClass {    
    @Test
    public void method1() throws InterruptedException {
        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        System.out.println("Before test-method. Thread id is: " + id);
    }
}
```

Please provide your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Adding a thread-count does not mean your test method will run multiple times. It means that their are multiple threads available for execution. Inyour case you have only one method in one test which will be executed only once. To the @Test annotation include an innvocationCount parameter. Read up the documentation - http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running

Comment: Could you please provide a example how I can execute parallel run for multiple testcases?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding parameters to `@Test` annotation:
`@Test(threadPoolSize = 4, invocationCount = 4)`
That will invoke your test four times from 4 different threads.

Comment: But it will apply for only 1 testcase. 
Suppose I have multiple testcases then I have to add parameters to all my testcases. If I have to increase/decrease run count for all the testcases. then changes will be a big task.

Answer (score 0):

If your need is that each of the @Test annotated methods that you write need to be executed "n" number of times (in parallel or in sequential order) without you having to explicitly add the `invocationCount` attribute on your own, you should be leveraging an [IAnnotationTransformer](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IAnnotationTransformer.html) using which you can on the fly change values of your `@Test` annotated method. You can try injecting this listener either via the suite file using the `<listeners>` tag or via Service Loaders. For more general information on listeners you can perhaps take a look at [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/listen-to-what-i-have-to-say-about-testng-listeners/) blog post of mine.